# Dynamically separate array to subarrays based on property with rx.js?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have the next input array. It can have different phases.

```
[
  {
  "id": 1,
  "phase": "Planning",
  },
  {
  "id": 2,
  "phase": "Planning",
  },
  {
  "id": 3,
  "phase": "Done",
  }
]
```

Based on phases I want to convert it to array with next format.

```
  [{title: 'Planning',
      datasets: {data: [/* 1st item will be here*/]},
               {data: [/* 2nd item will be here*/]}]},
      {title: 'Done',
          datasets: [{data: [/* 1st item will be here*/]}]
        }
      ];
```

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you really need to use RxJS for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need rxjs for this, you can achieve it using only javascript. Here's a ES6 implementation :

```js
let input = [
      {
      "id": 1,
      "phase": "Planning",
      },
      {
      "id": 2,
      "phase": "Planning",
      },
      {
      "id": 3,
      "phase": "Done",
      }
    ]
    
    let response = {};
    
    
    input.forEach(phaseObj=> {
    
      if(!!response[phaseObj["phase"]])
        response[phaseObj["phase"]].push({data: phaseObj})
      else
        response[phaseObj["phase"]] = [{data: phaseObj}]
    })
    
    response = Object.keys(response).map( key=> { return {title: key, datasets : response[key]}});
    console.log(response)
```

if you really insist on using rxjs, you can do something like :

```
let response = {};

Rx.Observable.from(input).map(phaseObj=> {
  if(!!response[phaseObj["phase"]])
    response[phaseObj["phase"]].push({data: phaseObj})
  else
    response[phaseObj["phase"]] = [{data: phaseObj}]
})
  .toArray()
  .subscribe( ()=> {
    response = response = Object.keys(response).map( key=> { return {title: key, datasets : response[key]}});
    console.log(response);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [groupBy](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/groupby.html) operator - it will group your data by object property

Comment: And how can I get next format? 
{'title': 'Planning',
 'datasets': {data: [/* 1st item will be here*/]},

Comment: You can map as you want - `...groupBy(data).pipe(toArray()),map(` _mapFnToDesiredFormat_ `)...`. So, for example you have `[{title: 'B2', name: "Sue"},{title: 'B2', name: "Frank"}]` as first group. Map fn is `(v) => ({title: v[0].title, datasets:{data:[v[0]]}})`.